# ReactJS Dropdown Refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a react project, which involves using a dropdown with accounts. The problem is that the page refreshes every few seconds, and the dropdown clears itself and for a split second becomes empty with that refresh. Is there a way I can resolve this? The dropdown works well when the options are preset, but it has errors when I use accounts.map in order to iterate through each account. All help is greatly appreciated!

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  let accounts = ["email1","email2","email3"];
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <select
        type="select"
        name="orderState"
        id="orderState"
      >       
      {accounts.map(account => (
        <option>{account}</option>
      ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I may have jumped the gun in my answer: `The problem is that the page refreshes every few seconds` - what does this mean?

Comment: So the page basically refreshes information from the backend so that if there are any updates or anything, you don't have to manually reload the page. It doesn't reload the page completely, rather just updates the information. The problem there is that upon this refresh, the dropdown is also refreshed, so the dropdown is refreshed.

Comment: In that case, you probably just need to maintain the state of the selected dropdown, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain it the selected value in state:

```js
let accounts = ["email1", "email2", "email3"];
export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <select
        type="select"
        name="orderState"
        id="orderState"
        onChange={e => setSelected(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option>Select an account</option>
        {accounts.map(account => (
          <option selected={account === selected}>{account}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-df2ddj?file=src/App.js)